# Gradle. JUnit lib is not visible after tests generation

Tags: java, junit, gradle

In my project I dynamically generate source code. 
Now I want to generate tests for it.

Source code is generated successfully with following gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

configurations {pmd}

android {
    ...
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        preBuild.dependsOn genSources
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'target/generated-sources/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
}

task genSources << {
    println "Generating sources...."
    ant.fmpp configuration:"src/main/resources/codegen/config.fmpp",
        sourceRoot:"src/main/resources/codegen/templates",
        outputRoot:"target/generated-sources/main/java";
}

dependencies {        
    ...
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    ...
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.sourceforge.fmpp', name: 'fmpp', version: '0.9.14'
    }

    ant.taskdef(name: 'fmpp', classname:'fmpp.tools.AntTask', classpath: buildscript.configurations.classpath.asPath)
}
```

**sourceSets** have a link to generated source code. 
So, as result I can use it from app's source code.

Currently I think how to generate tests, in which folder generate it and how to link them with junit library.

I used similar logic for that. (Absolutely not sure correct it or not)
I created one more task for tests generation:

```
task genTests << {
    println "Generating tests...."
    ant.fmpp configuration:"src/main/resources/codegen/config.fmpp",
        sourceRoot:"src/main/resources/codegen/templates/tests",
        outputRoot:"target/generated-sources/main/java/tests";
}
```

added this task to build process

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn genSources
    preBuild.dependsOn genTests
}
```

and in the `sourceSets` added following lines:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'target/generated-sources/main/java'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'target/generated-sources/main/java/tests'
        }
    }
}
```

In `android studio` files have following structure:

```
java
    com.package.model
    com.package.model(test)
```

**As the result** tests are generated, but 
they generated in separate folder, like

```
 java
    com.package.model
    com.package.model(test)
    com.generatedpackage.model <--- here (physical location is in target folder)
```

and `junit` library is not found:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Cannot resolve symbol Test.

What is correct way for tests generation? Or at least how to add dependency for `junit` for tests?